# Error _co.routeToBrainstoming is not a function in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've made a function in Angular 2 that's structured the same as any other function in the application (but the content is different), but when run it's creating an error `_co.routeToBrainstoming is not a function`.

The function is pretty straight forward and just triggers a service:

```
routeToBrainstorming():void {
    // Send name to API
    this._nmapi
    .getService("user/add/" + name)
    .then((result) => {
      // Move to next screen
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/brainstoming');
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```

The service is to access an API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class NmapiService {

  private _baseUrl = "http://localhost:59819/";
  modules: any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    console.log('Novel Machine API V1.0 (Beta) Initialized...');
  }

  // On successful API call
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  // On Error in API Call
  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

  // Basic Get W/ No Body
  getService(url: string): Promise<any> {
    return this._http
        .get(this._baseUrl + url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

The API is local and is running - but doesn't actually return any data - it just adds an entry to a database with a guid as a primary key. So all it 'returns' as such is a status 200 ok http response.

Comment: Looks like a simple typo: The function is called `routeToBrainstorming` but your error says `routeToBrainstoming`

Comment: Ah wow - thanks! Totally didn't see that!